# Minimize primefaces dialog from beacking bean

Tags: java, html, primefaces

Is there any way to minimize a primefaces dialog from backing bean?  I have two dialogs. When i click a button in dialog one i want to open the second dialog and minimize the first.

Comment: Please show us a (minimal) code example from what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is a minimisable demo for a Primefaces dialog, which i guess handles the minimisation with java script but i was not able to find that code. There are java script function to hide and show a dialog "PF('dialog').hide();" but there is no similar ".minimize();" function. That's why i'm asking for help, because i could not find anything to try yet.

Comment: Download the source, check the client-side js of this component and you'll be able to solve this. Effectively it boils down to calling javascript from a backing bean for which there are multiple Q/A in stackoverflow

Comment: Are you sure you strictly need to manage this in the backing bean? Usually there's some workaround to do it in the facelet file. Apart from that, it doesn't seem user friendly to hide a dialog and show other one, I would rather refresh its content.

Comment: @Kukeltje. Thanks. I found this PF('dialog').toggleMinimize();. This works fine.